# How to set no History for all Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

My Android Application is based on four Activities. The last activity starts an Intent Service and set itself to background.

Before I sent the last Activity to background I would like to remove all four Activities from backstack history

I tried already to set the no history = true attribute for the activities. This causes errors when I use startActivityForResult, so I need a different solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think there is an "good" way to do this, I would try something like this:

First create a `SelfClosingActivity` which only job is to close itself after opening:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState()) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    finish();
}
```

When you want to close all the Activities (after you start your IntentService I guess) run the `SelfClosingActivity` and add flags to clear the current stack.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelfClosingActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear the current stack before opening `SelfClosingActivity` and `SelfClosingActivity` will close itself leaving the stack completely empty.

Comment: but I would like to remove all activites from the history stack. my last activity starts an Intent Service which is running in the background

Comment: so what do you want to show to the user while the IntentService runs?

Comment: I will show nothing to the User. the IntentService will run in Background (uploading a large file) for a longer time. After finishing the upload it will sent a Notification to the User

Answer (score 0):

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** will do what you want.

> **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**
>
> Added in API level 1 int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP If set, and the
>   activity being launched is already running in the current task, then
>   instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other
>   activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be
>   delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.
>
> This launch mode can also be used to good effect in conjunction with
>   **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**: if used to start the root activity of a task,
>   it will bring any currently running instance of that task to the
>   foreground, and then clear it to its root state. This is especially
>   useful, for example, when launching an activity from the notification
>   manager.

Refer to [Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for more info